# Need to pass 2D array to function and find sum of row c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So I need to create a function to find the sum of rows in my 2D array. Array is fixed, matrix[5][5], and user inputs 25 integers.

I know how to find the sum of my rows using the following code:

```
//for sake of ease lets say user inputs numbers 1-25
for (r = 0; r < 5; r++)
{
  for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
  {
     sum = sum + matrix[r][c]
  }
  cout << "\n" << sum;
  sum = 0;
}


//the code above will display the sum of each row as follows:
15
40
65
90
115
```

I want to display the totals for each row as

```
Row 1:
Sum =

Row 2:
Sum =

etc...
```

How do I pass the array to a function in order to find the sum of each row and how do I separate the individual sum of rows to display like I want?

I have read a chapter on passing multidimensional arrays to functions like 4 times over in a c++ beginners book, I have read and looked at many different forums online and maybe it is because I have been starring at it for too long I am not seeing the answer but I have given myself a headache. I really just want to understand how to pass it. I have tried to modify the passing of an array to a function to find the sum of all the integers in the array but I could not get it to work for what I needed.

ETA(10/7/2017 1535 PCT):
So I am trying the following to try and pass my 2D array to a function and calculate the sum...

```
void total(int matrix[][5], int n, int m)
    {     // I am getting an error here though that states "expected a ';' "
        for (r = 0; r < n; r++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
                sum += matrix[r][c];

        }
        cout << "Row " << r << " = " << sum << endl;
    }
```

Is this even how you create a function with a 2D array?

ETA (10/7/2017 2100 PCT)

So I think I figured out how to pass the array, but I cannot seem to get it to do the proper math, meaning this does not sum up the rows....

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int total( const int [][5], int, int);

int main()
{
    int c, r, matrix[5][5];

    cout << "Please input any 25 numbers you'd like, seperated by a space, then press enter:" << endl;

    for (r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            cin >> matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
    getchar();

    cout << endl << "Matrix: " << endl;
    for (r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            cout << matrix[r][c] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Please press the enter key to get the sums of each row << endl;
    getchar();

    cout << "Sum = " << total << endl; //this displays "Sum = 013513F2"
    system("PAUSE");
}


int total(const int matrix[][5], int R, int C)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < C; c++)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to actually store the sums? You just need to add another line to output the rows above the line that outputs the sum and change that. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just want to know how to do it. I know how to add a 6th row to show the sum of columns or add a 6th column to show sum of rows. I was just wondering how to display it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array of any dimension can be done by using the syntax: `type (&name)[numElements]` by reference. Or by pointer you would replace the `&` with a `*`. Below is a basic example that compiles, which passes the array by reference to the `pass2Darray` function. Alternatively, you could simply use a regular array with size `[5 * 5]` to ensure that it's entirely contiguous. Since a 2D array is not natively something that exists in C++. And then, since you're working with matrices, you can access it in column major by `[row * i + col]` or in row major by `[col * j + row]`.

```
#include <iostream>

// Reference to multiArray
// int (&someName)[num][num]

// Pointer to multiArray
// int (*someName)[num][num]

void pass2Darray(int (&passed)[1][1]) {
    std::cout << passed[0][0];
}

int main() {

    int arr[1][1] = { {1} };
    pass2Darray(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help the future readers this is what I came up with. Took a lot of research and a million different trial and errors but here it is:

```
int math(int a[5]) //The function the array has been passed to
{
    //Declaring the variables in the function 
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;

    min = a[0]; //setting the minimum value to compare to

    for (int C = 0; C < 5; C++) //Creates the loop to go through the row elements 
    {
        sum = sum + a[C];   // calculates the sum of each row
        if (a[C] < min) min = a[C];  //assigns the element of lowest value from row
        if (a[C] > max) max = a[C];  //assigns the element of highest value from row
    }
    average = sum / 5;  //calculates the average of each row

        cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;     //Outputs sum
        cout << "Average = " << average << endl;   //Outputs average
        cout << "Min = " << min << endl;  //Outputs min
        cout << "Max = " << max << endl;  //Oututs max
        cout << endl;
        return 0; //return value for function
}
```

Down the line that calls the function and displays the output I was looking for:

```
for (r = 0; r < 5; r++) //sets up row loop for display
{
    cout << "Row " << r+1 << ":" << endl;
    math(matrix[r]); //displays calculations done in math function
    cout << endl;
}
```

Hope this helps someone down the road...